# How to draw straight line in d3.js (horizontally and vertically)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have doubts in drawing the line graph concept. Can anybody explain these coordinates?

`x1=5,x2=10,y1=10,y2=30`

Please explain each attribute and what it represents. Also, please give me an idea about drawing a straight line vertically and also horizontally (like a cross-hair).

I am total newbie to d3.js graphs, so please help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A line is a simple line between two points and is described by four required attributes.

- x1: The x position of the first end of the line as measured from the
  left of the screen.
- y1: The y position of the first end of the line
  as measured from the top of the screen.
- x2: The x position of the
  second end of the line as measured from the left of the screen.
- y2:
  The y position of the second end of the line as measured from the top
  of the screen.

The following is an example of the code section required to draw a line;

```
holder.append("line")          // attach a line
    .style("stroke", "black")  // colour the line
    .attr("x1", 100)     // x position of the first end of the line
    .attr("y1", 50)      // y position of the first end of the line
    .attr("x2", 300)     // x position of the second end of the line
    .attr("y2", 150);    // y position of the second end of the line
```

This will produce a line as follows;

[image]

The line extends from the point 100,50 to 300,150 (x1,y1 to x2,y2).

You can see it in more context [here](https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read#leanpub-auto-line).

This doesn't cover the cross-hair example, but once you understand the part above it should be clearer.

Comment: Yea it was really helpful and i read your blog only for d3.js

Comment: maybe you'd rather add a class for css styling than styling inline: `holder.append("line").attr("class", "sigmaline").[...]`. Just add a `<style>` block inside you document where `holder` resides. External css resources included via `<script src="somewhere.css">` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @d3noob, would you mind looking at this issue for me please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891097/d3-draw-grid-line-at-a-location-based-on-the-y-coordinates/44895185?noredirect=1#comment76805699_44895185

Comment: Why do we use `style` for one and `attr` for another?

Comment: I like to think that an attribute of an element is something that is a characteristic of the object without defining it, and/or it may affect the object’s position or orientation on the page. There could be a strong argument to say that styles could be seen to cross-over into attributes and I agree. I like to think that an element can be selected and arranged on a web page with select and attr, but once it’s there, changes to how it looks are a matter for style.

Comment: Does anyone know where to find an example how to update the line if the scale would change?

Comment: You might want to start with Mike's pan and zoom example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/db6b4335bf1662b413e7968910104f0f

Answer (score 1):

To draw a line we need TWO points, in a graph if we want to refer any point we use co-ordinates, (x1,y1) is the start point of a line (x2,y2) is the end point of a line, these two points are connected.

To draw a grid in graph refer this link http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-grid-lines-to-d3js-graph.html If you are not understanding, then ask.Okay

Comment: Can you explain something more about line co-ordinates and how d3.js plot it with the points?

Comment: @divakar, take a look at [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-multi-line-chart-using-d3js--cms-22935). Scroll down to the "Creating the Line" section.