# d3-Draw grid line at a location based on the y coordinates?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am kind a new to d3.js and want to draw a horizontal grid line based on y coordinate value [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/praveenuics/two5g2td/) , i've tried with if condition at y1 and y2 locations but the lines are overlapping at the top of graph.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: On the y of the mouse?

Comment: @Lex, could you please elaborate your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statement makes little sense to me:

```
if (y(d) === thresholdValues.minValue) {
    return y(d);
}
```

This means that only when the value in the screen is exactly `thresholdValues.minValue` (which is `40` in your code) the line will be painted.

Solution: drop the `if` statement. Actually, I kept the `if` just to avoid the first gridline, over the x axis:

```
if (d != 0) {
    return y(d);
}
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 50
};

var thresholdValues = {
  minValue: 40,
  maxValue: 85
};
var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
  .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
  .orient("left").ticks(5);

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.close);
  });

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
var data = [{
  date: "1-May-12",
  close: "58.13"
}, {
  date: "30-Apr-12",
  close: "53.98"
}, {
  date: "27-Apr-12",
  close: "67.00"
}, {
  date: "26-Apr-12",
  close: "89.70"
}, {
  date: "25-Apr-12",
  close: "99.00"
}];

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.close = +d.close;
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.date;
}));
y.domain([0, 100]);

svg.append("path") // Add the valueline path.
  .attr("d", valueline(data));

svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g") // Add the Y Axis
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.selectAll("line.horizontalGrid").data(y.ticks(4)).enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr({
    "class": "horizontalGrid",
    "x1": margin.right,
    "x2": width - margin.right,
    "y1": function(d) {
      if (d != 0) {
        return y(d);
      }
    },
    "y2": function(d) {
      if (d != 0) {
        return y(d);
      }
    },
    "fill": "none",
    "shape-rendering": "crispEdges",
    "stroke": "grey",
    "stroke-width": "2px",
    "opacity": 0.4,
    "stroke-dasharray": 8
  });
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px Arial;
}

path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 1;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT: If you want to draw only two lines, at the thresholds, you have to pass their values to `data`, not the scale ticks:

```
.data(Object.values(thresholdValues))
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 50
};

var thresholdValues = {
  minValue: 40,
  maxValue: 85
};
var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
  .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
  .orient("left").ticks(5);

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.close);
  });

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
var data = [{
  date: "1-May-12",
  close: "58.13"
}, {
  date: "30-Apr-12",
  close: "53.98"
}, {
  date: "27-Apr-12",
  close: "67.00"
}, {
  date: "26-Apr-12",
  close: "89.70"
}, {
  date: "25-Apr-12",
  close: "99.00"
}];

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.close = +d.close;
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.date;
}));
y.domain([0, 100]);

svg.append("path") // Add the valueline path.
  .attr("d", valueline(data));

svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g") // Add the Y Axis
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.selectAll("line.horizontalGrid").data(Object.values(thresholdValues)).enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr({
    "class": "horizontalGrid",
    "x1": margin.right,
    "x2": width - margin.right,
    "y1": function(d) {
      if (d != 0) {
        return y(d);
      }
    },
    "y2": function(d) {
      if (d != 0) {
        return y(d);
      }
    },
    "fill": "none",
    "shape-rendering": "crispEdges",
    "stroke": "grey",
    "stroke-width": "2px",
    "opacity": 0.4,
    "stroke-dasharray": 8
  });
```

```css
path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 1;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time, based on your suggestion i've tried few different things like if(d===thresholdValues.minValue or maxValue) return y(d) -> this works fine but as i mentioned the rest of the lines are overlapping each other on top of the graph. just recognised that if the threshold values are 0, 20, 40, 60, 80 and 100 i.e., anything that are matching to y axis values are painting out the line. if i want to paint the line at 78 or 89 threshold value , it doesn't work.

Comment: @praveenuics In that case, you're passing the wrong values to `data`. Check my edit.